# resolution needed, argument 1 must have a 'write' method. make a dictionary into a csv

Tags: python, csv

i cant seem to get my code working its keeps giving me the same 'argument 1 must have a 'write' method

```
import csv
tank1 = [{'tank':1, 'product':['condenstate'], 'temp':12,'ullage':21000, 'level':70000}]
tank2 = [{'tank':2, 'product':['condenstate'], 'temp':12,'ullage':21000, 'level':70000}]
key1 = tank1,tank2[0].keys()
with open('motherwell.csv','w',newline='') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer 

    writer = csv.writer(output_file, key1)
    writer = csv.writer(key1)
```

Comment: Try indenting your code properly  and paste again.

Comment: What is the point of assigning to `writer` 3 times?

Comment: Suggest you read this:  http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/

Comment: ok thanks i will only been learning python for a week now stuck on this task

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `key1`?

Comment: im trying to get the dictionaries into the writer and i've looked all over stackoverflow and thats how most people have formatted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain what you are trying to achieve, but you probably need just this:

```
with open('motherwell.csv','w', newline='') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    writer.writerow(tank1)
    writer.writerow(tank2)
```

Note:  this is for Python 3, for Python 2 you need to open the file as binary (`wb`).

Comment: my bad should of explained better im trying to get the dictionaries to be reformatted into csv files and have the data ive displayed p.s. sorry again bad at explain